# Node js ACL Error 'Callback was already called'

Tags: node.js, acl

I am using express in node js. I use for ACL module : https://github.com/OptimalBits/node_acl

When it works app, created acl collections in MongoDb. But , Error occured  acl.allow() method. I get errors.

Code :

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var node_acl = require('acl');
var acl = "";

var app = express();

mongodb.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/acl', _mongo_connected);

function _mongo_connected(error, db) {
  var mongoBackend = new node_acl.mongodbBackend(db /*, {String} prefix   */ );
  // Create a new access control list by providing the mongo backend
  //  Also inject a simple logger to provide meaningful output
   acl = new node_acl(mongoBackend);

   // Defining roles and routes
   set_roles();
   }

function set_roles() {

  // Define roles, resources and permissions
  acl.allow([{
   roles: 'admin',
   allows: [{
     resources: '/secret',
     permissions: 'create'
   }, {
     resources: '/topsecret',
     permissions: '*'
   }]
   }, {
   roles: 'user',
     allows: [{
     resources: '/secret',
     permissions: 'get'
   }]
  }, {
   roles: 'guest',
   allows: []
  }]);

 Code continue ...
 ..
 .
 ..


 }
```

Error :

```
process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                    ^
Error: Callback was already called.
at node_modules/acl/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:43:36
at node_modules/acl/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:694:17
at node_modules/acl/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:173:37
at node_modules/acl/lib/mongodb-backend.js:134:18
at handleCallback (node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:95:12)
at node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:845:28
at handleCallback (node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:95:12)
at node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:1538:5
at handleCallback (node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:95:12)
at node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:273:5
at node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:756:13
```

Comment: Seems like a bug in `acl`? https://github.com/OptimalBits/node_acl/blob/master/lib/mongodb-backend.js#L128 & https://github.com/OptimalBits/node_acl/blob/master/lib/mongodb-backend.js#L133 will definitely lead to it being called twice.

Comment: How can ?
 like : if (err) {
            cb(err);
          } else {
            cb(true);
          }

Comment: Both the lines I linked to are called in parallel, but it doesn't wait for them both. When one finished, `cb` will be called, and then when the second one is finished, the `cb` will be called a second time.

Comment: I changed code in this way. But some error. if (err instanceof Error) {
            cb(err);
          } else {
            cb(undefined);
          }

Comment: Bug fix. https://github.com/OptimalBits/node_acl/issues/142#issuecomment-130586133